# How to find scala api documentation for string class

Tags: scala

How to find the API for the `String` class in Scala. Specifically I need to read the `exists` method.

Comment: -3 downvotes for legitimate question :|

Answer (score 6):

You can't find documentation for the `String` class itself in [Scala API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/index.html) because it isn't a Scala class, it's from the Java standard library, so you can find its documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html. Scala-specific methods like `exists` are added to it using implicit conversions in [`scala.Predef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$), which has this to say about `String`:

> [The String type in Scala has methods that come either from the underlying Java String (see the documentation corresponding to your Java version, for example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) or are added implicitly through scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$@String=String)

Comment: Thanks Alexey, it solved my problem, i am marking it as my answer

Comment: You haven't actually accepted the answer though (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

There's the online docs and in Scala 2.11.8 the REPL can provide interactive API documentation.

```
scala> val s = "foo"
s: String = foo

scala> s.exists
   override def exists(p: Char => Boolean): Boolean
```

When I type s. and then hit tab the function definition for `exists` is shown. So, if we want to see if "f" exists in `s` we can use the definition shown for `exists`. i.e.

```
scala> s.exists(c => c == 'f')
res0: Boolean = true
```

Comment: As @AlexeyRomanov mentioned there's no online docs about String as it's a Java class.